# url mapping in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I new to servlet and trying to find a way to get the values from url for example `/api/v1/http://localhost:8080/getInfo/product/1/order/22` So I know how to map url `getInfo` in web.xml. All I am looking for a way to get the product value and order value from url. How we do this in servlet? Any direction will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you give us your servlet declaration and mapping in web.xml? Also, what are you trying to do, GET, POST, PUT..?

Comment: I am mapping /getInfo url in servlet. Its a get request and I want to get the value of product and order id from http://localhost:8080/getInfo/product/{product_id}/order/{order_id}

Comment: and why not localhost:8080/getInfo?product=product_id&order=order_id

Comment: I can do that but thats how api is designed. I cannot use product and order id as query string.

Answer (score 0):

following the conversation, I would suggest to use
request.getPathInfo() to get any information appended to the servlet url and then parse it depending on your params names.